# Method Dir.mkdir throws Errno::EACCES

Tags: ruby, file, io, permissions

I have a weird, re-occurring bug in my code. Rarely,the method `Dir.mkdir` throws `` `mkdir': Permission denied - <file_name> (Errno::EACCES) ``, surprisingly, sometimes it just works (without any single change in code or anything whatsoever).

Here's the code:

```
    data.each_with_index do |row, index|

      #Make directory for each row:
      row_name = "row_#{index}";
       #Dir.rmdir just in-case, same error occurs without it.
      (FileUtils.rm_r(row_name) || Dir.rmdir(row_name)) if File.exist?(row_name) #Remove previous directory
      Dir.mkdir(row_name);
      row.each_with_index do |(key, value), index|
        #Make file for every record
        File.open("#{row_name}/#{index}.rtf", 'w') do |f|

        f.write value

        f.close #Just in-case, even though it's automatically called(no change without it)

        end    
      end
  end
```

The error occurs rarely(about once for every 4 times this code is executed).

## Misc:

- Wndows 7 platform
- No file was accessed at the time of execution
- Using CMD as administrator.

Why am I getting this error even though no changes were made to the code?
Could it be from the excessive creation of directories?(~60 directories are created by average for each execution)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by the OS blocking the script from deleting files too quickly, the solution was to delete all files before entering the loop. Worked perfectly.